# Require Factory class in Extension Method

Tags: c#, design-patterns, dependency-injection, extension-methods, factory-pattern

I am working on a large legacy C# application and a task assigned to me is to remove all usages of a static factory class `ServiceLocator.GetObject<T>()` and replace with constructor injected dependencies throughout.

For the most part, this is simple, however there are around 50 cases in the application codebase where this is a bit tricky. For instance, `Servicelocator` is used in a static class, or extension method, or even a WPF MarkupExtension!.

For instance, if you were faced with a code snippet like this, what would you do? (apart from cry)

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    private static ISingletonServiceOne _ServiceOne = null;
    private static ISingletonServiceTwo _ServiceTwo = null; // etc ... 

    public static SummaryHeader GetBannerSummary(this IModel rfq, object requester)
    {
        Guard.ArgumentNotNull(rfq, "rfq");
        Guard.ArgumentNotNull(requester, "requester");

        if (_ServiceOne == null)
        {
            _ServiceOne = ServiceLocator.GetService<ISingletonServiceOne>(requester);
            Guard.ArgumentNotNull(_ServiceOne, "_ServiceOne");
        }

        return _ServiceOne.GetBannerSummary(rfq);
    }
```

In the above the ServiceLocator.GetObject() method has been used in an Extension Method on IModel to locate a singleton registered service and execute a method on that using IModel.

The question is:

- Are there any patterns/practices to avoid this sort of thing - a DI container needed in a static class, value-converter or extension method
- Are there any patterns/practices to deal with cyclic dependencies in DI?
- What would you do in the above given there is a trade off between good code and time to delivery?

I am thinking to move the GetBannerSummary() method out of extensions and only IModel in this case, however (don't laugh) there are also cases of the same ServiceLocator being used in ValueConverters (WPF) and MarkupExtensions :0

Your comments/suggestions appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only time I would ever use ServiceLocator is in static methods, e.g. extension methods, and IValueConverters as, unfortunately, there really isn't any other good way of getting dependencies.

The only (slightly) better solution is to move the ServiceLocator call out to a lazy loaded property, so that the dependency can be injected during unit testing.

In your case, however, that won't fly as you have a requester property being passed to the GetService, in which case you ideally need to add an IServiceOneFactory dependency to which you can pass your requester object. So:

```
public interface IServiceOneFactory
{
    ISingletonServiceOne Create(object requester);
}

public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static IServiceOneFactory ServiceOneFactory
    {
        get 
        {
            if( _ServiceOneFactory==null)
                _ServiceOneFactory = ServiceLocator.GetService<IServiceOneFactory>();
            return _ServiceOneFactory;
        }
        set { _ServiceOneFactory = value; }
    }

    private static IServiceOneFactory _ServiceOneFactory = null;
    private static ISingletonServiceOne _ServiceOne = null;
    private static ISingletonServiceTwo _ServiceTwo = null; // etc ... 

    public static SummaryHeader GetBannerSummary(this IModel rfq, object requester)
    {
        Guard.ArgumentNotNull(rfq, "rfq");
        Guard.ArgumentNotNull(requester, "requester");

        if (_ServiceOne == null)
        {
            _ServiceOne = ServiceOneFactory.Create(requester);
            Guard.ArgumentNotNull(_ServiceOne, "_ServiceOne");
        }

        return _ServiceOne.GetBannerSummary(rfq);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi mark, thanks for the answer - I edited out Requestor as internally the implementation of ServiceLocator actually does nothing with it! Agree on your prognosis. Its a fairly shocking web of spaghetti I'm dealing with here so any suggestions to break it up are welcome : )

Comment: Hi Andrew, you're welcome - we've all had to go through it! I think you're doing everything right but I don't see a way around ServiceLocator in statics, extensions etc. It's a necessary evil if you've kept all your dependencies modular, as you should.

Comment: Yes big refactor underway as a requirement has come in to re-use a big chunk of code as a prism "Module" in another project. My reaction when I heard it was "lol". Anyway out of 120 usages of ServiceLocator I've gotten down to 60. I think I can trim more but some may stay if there is no 'easy-ish' solution. Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

Is it an option to inject `IServiceX` into your classes instead of using the a static accessor class? Perhaps make `GetBannerSummary` method part of an abstract base class that implements `IModel`?

DI does not fly when you don't control object instantiation. Triggers, Behaviors or Markup-Extensions in WPF fall into that category. There is no option to using a ServiceLocator there.

Comment: Hmm as I suspected watson ... Seems I'm going to have to do an awful lot of work to untangle this spaghetti